# How to make a rotating propeller and a helicopter body as one object? Is it possible to use shape keys to combine the two into one helicopter?

Tags: python

How to use python to combine a rotating propeller and a helicopter body into one object? I want to use the combined helicopter as a particle instance.

Comment: Add all the helicopter bits to one collection. Instance the collection.

Comment: Hi. I think it would be better to focus on your actual goal: "How to use a group of objects as a particle instance?" as opposed to your proposed solution: "How to combine animated objects into one?". See the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).